# Prove the existence of a CONTINUOUS rigid motion

Tags: continuity, solution-verification, classical-mechanics, isometry, orthogonal-matrices

**Definition**

A square matrix $A$ is said to be orthogonal if
$$
AA^T=I
$$
that is a square matrix is orthogonal if their columns determine an orthonormal reference frame.

---

---

---

Now if $\mathscr E:=\{\hat e:i=1,\dots,n\}$ is the standard basis, then the points
$$
E_i=O+\hat e_i
$$
belong to the $n$-persphere $\Bbb S^n$ and obviously determine an orthonormal affine frame $\mathcal E$: so we can surely imagine to move them **rigidly** along $\Bbb S^n$ to an another **given** orthonormal affine frame $\mathcal F$, since the linear transformation whose matrix $Q$ is defined by the orthonormal vectors of $\mathcal F$ does this; but unfortunately I am not able to prove that I can do this continuously, that is I am not able to prove that, for any orthonormalisation affine frame $\mathcal F$, there exists a collection $\mathfrak Q:=\{Q_t :t\in [0,1]\}$ of orthogonal matrices such that
$$
Q_0=I\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,Q_1=Q
$$
and such that the function
$$
\varphi(x,t):=Q_tx
$$
is continuous on $\Bbb R^n\times[0,1]$
so that I thought to pay a specific question. I point out I am really interested to the three-dimensional case. So, could anyone help me, please?

Comment: You must take in consideration orientation: in order such a motion to exist, it is necessary the frame to be positively oriented

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula

Comment: @user619894 Oh yeah, pheraps I understood what you want mean: it is not hard do this when the motion is a rotation along a given axis and thus we can make the map $\varphi$ with three rotation using the Euler angles, right?

Comment: find a finite rotation, then use theta as the smooth parameter

Comment: @user619894 Oh, I really like your advice: however unfortunately after dinner I am usual to study set theory and not physics; anyway tomorrow I surely will apply your suggest. Obviously if you want post an answer where you debate rigorously your solution I will happy. In any case thansk for your suggest! It was usefull!